# discord.js multi select menus can't run more than one value code when I selected two or more than two options & can't reply more than one interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to make a multi select menus with a collector and this is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu,Permissions} = require("discord.js");
const color_roles = require("quick.db")

module.exports = {
  name: "color-roles", 
  category: "Settings", 
  aliases: ["colorroles"], 
  cooldown: 1, 
  usage: "color-roles", 
  description: "Set color roles", 
  memberpermissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
  requiredroles: [], 
  alloweduserids: [], 
  minargs: 0, 
  maxargs: 0,
  minplusargs: 0, 
  maxplusargs: 0, 
  argsmissing_message: "", 
  argstoomany_message: "", 
    run: async (client, message, args, plusArgs, cmdUser, text, prefix) => {
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return message.reply("<:pepe_no:900701245419974686> **I don't have** `MANAGE_ROLES` **permission in this server which is needed to setup the color roles**")
if(message.guild.me.roles.highest.position < 15)  return message.reply("<:pepe_no:900701245419974686> **My role need to be higher than 15 so that i can setup the color roles!**")
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINSTRATTOR)) return message.reply("<:pepe_no:900701245419974686> **I don't have** `ADMINSTRATOR` **permission in this server which is needed to setup the color roles**")
      if (color_roles.has(message.guild.id+"_")) return message.reply("<:pepe_no:900701245419974686> **There is already have my color roles function running in this server, disable it to run a new one**")
      if (message.guild.roles.cache.size > 246) return message.reply("<:pepe_no:900701245419974686> **I couldn't create color roles if the server roles count is too close to the limit.**")
      const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('setup_option_of_color_roles')
        .setMinValues(1)
                    .setMaxValues(11)
                    .setPlaceholder('Enable or disable a color')
                    .addOptions([
                        {
                            label: 'Red',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: { id: "904319794180931624"},
                            value: 'red',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Magenta',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904309828271345714"},
                            value: 'magenta',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Aqua',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904323361079967785"},
                            value: 'aqua',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Morning Glory',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904320738574618685"},
                            value: 'morning_glory',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Lime',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904321773233930260"},
                            value: 'lime',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Forest Green',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904321409713602561"},
                            value: 'forest_green',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Yellow',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904322467122798603"},
                            value: 'yellow',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Gold',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904322921168769064"},
                            value: 'gold',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Sandy Brown',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904324015081017384"},
                            value: 'sandy_brown',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Silver',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904324628485378068"},
                            value: 'silver',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Turmeric',
                            //description: 'status: ',
              emoji: {id: "904325941000568903"},
                            value: 'turmeric',
                        },
                    ]),
            );
      let theembed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Color Roles")
      .addField("Red","disabled")
.addField("Magenta","disabled")
let msg = await message.reply({
  content:"halo",
  embeds: [theembed],
components:[row],
})
      
      const filter = i => {
    i.deferUpdate
     i.user.id === message.author.id;
};
      const collector = await message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter,componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 60000 });

      
collector.on('collect', async i => {
  
    if (message.author.id === i.user.id) {

      const filter = i => {

    return i.user.id === message.author.id;
};
const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 60000 })
      collector.on('collect', i => {
    if (i.user.id === message.author.id) {
    i.values.forEach(value => {
    if (value.includes("red")) {
i.reply("red")
      i.reply("red")
    }
if (value.includes("magenta")) {
i.reply("mag")
}
    })
        i.reply(`${i.user.id} clicked on the ${i.customId} button.`);
    } else {
        i.reply({ content: `These buttons aren't for you!`, ephemeral: true });
    }
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
});
    }
}
```

so the issue is when I selected one only , for example I choose red then I had wrote to let it reply with "red" , when I choose magenta and it will reply with "mag" . so when I choose more than two or two, for example: I choose red and magenta then it will only run one of the code (when I choose red and magenta it will only reply me with "red") means when I choose two or more than two it will only run one of the code of a value.
so I made something because I want to know why
I replaced

```js
if (value.includes("red")) {
i.reply("red")
      i.reply("red")
    }
```

with

```js
if (value.includes("red")) {
i.reply("red")
      i.reply("red")
      i.reply("red")
    }
```

I try to let it reply me two "red" when I choosed red
so now I go the multi select menus and choosed red and it only sent one "red" . why? it only run one code when I choose two or more than two! Can someone help me?

**edit:**
this is my new code: https://srcb.in/hQptLuRLrt (doesn't run any code)

Comment: @saoul thanks for helping , your code have no errors but it doesn't reply to the interaction

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using several if statements, use a switch block. This should be able to be infinitely scalable easily as well as send a new message every time. You want to have this outside your collector, the only thing your collector needs is to filter out people who aren't the message author. This way, the collector filters the responses, and the switch case decides what to do with the filtered ones. Absolutely should work, I have like 10 of these.

```
        function menuselection(i) {
        switch(i.values[0]) {
            case "red": 
                i.reply({content: "red", ephemeral: true})
            break;
            case "magenta": 
                i.reply({content: "mag", ephemeral: true})
            break;

        }
    }
```

**edit** - your collector should look something like this

```
        collector.on("collect", (i) => {
        if(i.message.id == msg.id) {
            if(i.member.id == message.author.id) 
                {i.reply(`${i.user.id} clicked on the 
                ${i.customId} button.`) menuselection(i)}
        else i.reply({content: "These buttons aren't for 
             you!", ephemeral: true})
        }
    })
```

Please try to avoid just copy and pasting as this code may lead to some errors (hopefully not) I just want to give you an idea of what the best way to use a menu is in my experience.